# Labelling on an 2d array C++ got the wrong result

Tags: c++

I am newbie and having work with connected components labelling algorithm.
My purpose is that I need to find out 3 block of light points and then calculate the coordinates of the central point of each block (kind of image processing).
But after I run the for loop, I got the same coordinate for all the central points of three blocks, and don't know what was going wrong.
Could someone here please help me!
Thanks a lot!

This is my code

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < 128; j++)
            {
                if (pInt[i * 128 + j] <= 18000) label[i][j] = 0;
                if (pInt[i * 128 + j] > 18000)
                {
                    if (label[i-1][j-1] != 0)
                    {
                        label[i][j] = label[i-1][j-1];
                    }
                    if (label[i-1][j] != 0)
                    {
                        label[i][j] = label[i-1][j];
                    }
                    if (label[i-1][j+1] != 0)
                    {
                        label[i][j] = label[i-1][j+1];
                    }
                    if (label[i][j-1] != 0)
                    {
                        label[i][j] = label[i][j-1];
                    }
                    if ((label[i - 1][j - 1] = 0) && (label[i - 1][j] = 0) && (label[i - 1][j + 1] = 0) && (label[i][j - 1] = 0))
                    {
                        l = l + 1;
                        label[i][j] = l;
                    }
                }
                if (label[i][j] = 1)
                {
                    count1++;
                    sumx1 = sumx1 + i;
                    sumy1 = sumy1 + j;
                }
                if (label[i][j] = 2)
                {
                    count2++;
                    sumx2 = sumx2 + i;
                    sumy2 = sumy2 + j;
                }
                if (label[i][j] = 3)
                {
                    count3++;
                    sumx3 = sumx3 + i;
                    sumy3 = sumy3 + j;
                }
            }
        }
        float y1 = (float)sumx1 / count1;
        float z1 = (float)sumy1 / count1;
        float y2 = (float)sumx2 / count2;
        float z2 = (float)sumy2 / count2;
        float ya = (float)sumx3 / count3;
        float za = (float)sumy3 / count3;
        printf("three points:\n1(%f, %f)\n2(%f, %f)\na(%f, %f)\n", z1 - 64, 64 - y1, z2 - 64, 64 - y2, za - 64, 64 - ya);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` statements you need to use the `==` operator to compare.  The single `=` is assignment.  For example:

```
if (label[i][j] == 1)
```

There are 6 places I see where you need to make this change.

Comment: Thank you so much.
That's fun that it could still work :P
I just edited and it seems like it worked better. Also I read from somewhere else and replace all the if by the if...else and it seems that it's a right decision ;)